# Change relative path of XSLT document() function to JBOSS class path

Tags: xslt

I have placed few configuration files including an xml file named `ClaimSystemConfig.xml` in JBOSS server under `conf` folder.  I am trying to call `document('ClaimSystemConfig.xml')` in an XSLT file.Here the problem is that the XSL file and XML file(ClaimSystemConfig.xml) are located in different directories under `conf` folder of JBOSS and the XSL file is expecting the xml file in the same directory where it exists. My directory structure is like this:

```
conf/XML/ClaimSystemConfig.xml

conf/XSL/xslfile.xsl
```

The xsl is taking the relative path as the same directory where it exists. Can we change the relative path to JBOSS `conf` folder instead of XSL directory? is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document('../XML/ClaimSystemConfig.xml')`
Else, you can also give the full filename of the xml.

e.g., `document('C:/documents/conf/XML/ClaimSystemConfig.xml')`

Comment: Plus one for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If the main input document is in a different directory too then try `document('ClaimSystemConfig.xml', /)` as that would resolve the URL relative to the one of the main input document.